# Идентификатор или сложный селектор

Tags: html, css, html5

Предположим есть элемент `header` расположенный непосредственно в `body` и являющийся шапкой сайта. В CSS можно обращаться к нему как `body > header`, в то же время можно дать ему идентификатор и обращаться по нему. Вопрос: существует ли общепринятый вариант идентификации: `id` или селектор? Каким образом лучше идентифицировать элемент?

Comment: Старайтесь как можно меньше использовать `class` и `id`, ну, конечно, чтобы не было такого, допустим, у Вас в каком-то контейнере 2 `ul`, то им уже нужно будет задавать классы, чтобы проще обращаться, если же 1, то можно и `%container% > ul`, примерно так, может, мой вариант не правильный, но я пользуюсь им давно и все сайты легко поддерживаются, что мной, что другими программистами

Comment: @meine, но если потом использовать БЭМ, то станет очень больно, ведь там не используются селекторы тегов и идентификаторов, а только классов.

Comment: @wcobalt, посмотрите, может станет более ясно. https://ru.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/